# How to run python 2.7 script in python 3.5 / Or what is the best option to run python scripts for 2.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

What is the most better way to use Python 2.7 code if I have installed Python 3 already?

I've never used a Python 2.7 because I am new in Python and most video tutorials and web topics said it's better to use Python 3.
But when I try to run code who is for 2.7 and not exist for Python 3, sometimes it's not working.
What is the better option. To use Python 2 and 3 both on my PC. Or to try looking for Python 3 code only. Or to modify somehow Python 2.7 code?
These are the errors:

```
IPython 6.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.

runfile('C:/Users/G/Desktop/image_recognition/new_test/GemData.py', wdir='C:/Users/G/Desktop/image_recognition/new_test')

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2862, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "<ipython-input-1-02441e959cce>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/G/Desktop/image_recognition/new_test/GemData.py', wdir='C:/Users/G/Desktop/image_recognition/new_test')

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 710, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 101, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/G/Desktop/image_recognition/new_test/GemData.py", line 19
    print "error: image not read from file \n\n"        # print error message to std out
                                               ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(print "error: image not read from file \n\n"        # print error message to std out)?
```

Comment: you can use virtualenvs to run differentpython versions on the same machine

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run your present code with Python 3 interpreter, so you have two options: translate this code to Python 3 or run it with Python 2.

**Porting 2 to 3**

There is some materials about porting from python 2 to 3:

[Official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html)

[DigitalOcean tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-port-python-2-code-to-python-3)

Also there is a tool for automated translation: [2to3](https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html).
I haven't use it by myself so I cannot recommend it, but you can have a look and decide if it suites your needs.

**Running with python 2**

I think the best way here is to create a [virtual environment](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) with python 2. Something like this

```
$ virtualenv -p python2 venv
$ source venv/bin/activate
$ python <your-script>.py
```

For the further reading, there are a techniques to write python 2/3 compatible code. [See this](http://python-future.org/compatible_idioms.html).